# How do I fast generate constructor and getter, setter in visual studio code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I was currently changed to VS Code after using Netbean IDE, and there are many short cut or code snippet that I don't know.
In Netbean, I can just use Ctrl + Space to fast generate Constructor, or right click and select insert code to get Constructor and Getter and Setter.
How do you do that in VS Code?
Thank you!

I tried Ctrl + Space like in Netbean but it doesn't work.

Comment: In my opinion if you are doing proper Java development and want to move away from NetBeans you would be much better served working the community edition of IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @BernardV thank you for your recommendation, i will try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Source Action` option. For example:

If you want to generate a `getter`, you select the variable and then `Right Click`:

[image: Right Click]

Next select `Source Action...`, and then select `Generate Getters`:

[image: Generate Getters]

Also, note that if you type `get` it automatically suggests `getName()`:

[image: getName()]